# Add a carat to a navigation item with the class active that doesn't push the nav icon out of the div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, navigation

I am creating a react navigation bar and want to highlight each nav item with a carat if a user is viewing a certain url/route. I am writing in sass and have been trying to add the carat with the psuedo class :after and am not having any luck. The SVG highlights successfully here with the active class.

What is the best approach here?

Here is my react navigational item for example:

```
getViewNavItem() {
    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    const dash= "/dashboard"

    return (
      <li className={ classNames({"active": currentPath === partners}, "sidebar-item view")}>
          <div data-place="right" data-type="dark" data-effect="solid" data-multiline="false" data-class="nav-tooltip" delayHide={2000} data-tip data-for='view'>
            <UiIcon icon="view-nav-text" dimensions={[25, 25]} />
          </div>
          <ReactTooltip id='view' globalEventOff='click'>
            <ul>
            <div className="sub-links">
              <li><a className="sidebar-sublinks" href="/dashboard">Dashboards</a></li>
            </div>
            </ul>
          </ReactTooltip>
      </li>
    );
  },
```

Sass:

```
.sidebar-item
      background-color: #242524
      margin-top: 30px
      font-size: 10px
      height: 65px
      text-align: center
      &.active
        svg
          path
            fill: white
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out
        &:after
          background-color: white
          border-bottom: 7px solid black !important
          border-top: 7px solid black !important
          border-right: 7px solid transparent !important
```

Comment: Have you verified that the CSS works regardless of what is going on in React? Because replicating your CSS in a test case does not result in a carat.

Regardless, a good solution would be to render the carat as a DOM element conditionally upon the React state. You're already changing the className dependent on a boolean, so why not take it a step further and render/not render a carat element based on the same condition? Bringing CSS into the mix just complicates things.

Comment: Im not sure I follow? are you saying to do something similar to `<li className={ classNames({"active": currentPath === partners}, "carat")}>` I create a carat/triagnle with CSS so im not sure I understand how that can be all together avoided

Comment: By the way where is the `partners` variable coming from? Is that in scope of your component or `render()`? Or is it supposed to be `currentPath === "partners"` (note the quote marks to make it a string)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CSS, conditionally render a DOM element for the carat:

```
getViewNavItem() {
    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    const dash= "/dashboard"

    return (
      <li className={ classNames("sidebar-item view")}>
          {
            currentPath === partners
            ?
              <div className="carat"></div> // Some kind of carat element
            :
              [] // Render nothing
          }
          <div data-place="right" data-type="dark" data-effect="solid" data-multiline="false" data-class="nav-tooltip" delayHide={2000} data-tip data-for='view'>
            <UiIcon icon="view-nav-text" dimensions={[25, 25]} />
          </div>
          <ReactTooltip id='view' globalEventOff='click'>
            <ul>
            <div className="sub-links">
              <li><a className="sidebar-sublinks" href="/dashboard">Dashboards</a></li>
            </div>
            </ul>
          </ReactTooltip>
      </li>
    );
}
```

Another thing I notice is that as it stands, the variable `partners` does not seem to be in the scope of `render()`. And even if it were, unless your component state or props are changed somehow, your `render()` function will not re-run so you might not be seeing updates to your app when they happen. Make sure your component lifecycle and prop/state updates are in order.